# Does resizing an ext4 partition formats it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I currently have my hard-disk divided in 3 ext4 partitions as shown in the image below.

[image: HDD Structure]

Now, recently I've been needing more space and I would like extend the `sda2` by shrinking the `sda1` and adding that space to it, preferably without losing any data.

Is there any way to achieve that? I saw an option to resize a partition and set free space preceding. Will that format the partition?

Thanks.

Comment: depending of your time, you should test on a virtual machine first. be sure to have a unmounted `fsck -F` on partition first.

Answer (score 2):

You must boot your system from a live Linux distro, then use [gparted](http://gparted.org/), available either as default or as extra package on all distros. There are guides to do this all over Google, you can find [one here](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) just as an example. However, despite all assurances, you should backup all of your data **in any case**, there is alway Murphy's law.

At the cost of sounding banal, let me just state you cannot shrink a partition to a size smaller than the amount currently stored on it, without losing data.

Don't you wish now you had used [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) instead, *ab initio?*

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that but I'm aware that I'd have to boot from another live distro. And I also know that I can't shrink to size smaller than the data stored in it :D. I was just worried about the data loss.

Comment: And I have no idea what LVM and ab initio is.

Comment: @NijrajGelani `ab initio` means from the very beginning (= at the time of installation, in this case). As for LVM, the link explains it.

Comment: Ah well... Okay. :D